# Ansible: How to assign an element to an array/variable which has dot in key-name?

Tags: arrays, ansible

I was adding few elements to an array, which is fetched from a file
The file contents are like

```
#shipping.yml
shipping.enabled: true
shipping.method: "postal"
country.states.availability: ["ST1", "ST2", "ST3"]
```

I'm trying to extract `country.states.available` from the file and add entries from another list to have more states and update the file back with new list

```
my playbook is something like
- include_vars:
     file: shipping.yml
     name: shipping_var

- set_fact:
    shipping_var['country.states.availability']: "shipping_var['country.states.availability'] + ['{{ item }}'] "
  loop: "{{ lookup ('file', 'new_state_list_per_line').splitlines()}}"

# And then I've to update the filename back to have the list with new states.availability
```

But getting error:

```
The variable name 'shipping_var['country.states.availability']' is not valid. 
Variables must start with letter or underscore and contain only letters, numbers, underscore
```

Any chance on how to update a variable with dot in the key-name?

Comment: A wild guess, but what happens if you try `country_states_availability`?

Comment: @KenY-N, it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `set_fact` to update directly a nested element. You have to use the top level element and work your way around. Note that your loop is not needed since you get a list you can directly concatenate to the existing one.

In your current situation you can fix the issue with the following. I broke the vars in different pieces in the task to have a readable final expression. I also added the `unique` and `sort` filter so that you produce the same result each time, even when running the task on an already updated file.

```yaml
- name: update var with new countries
  vars:
    new_states: "{{ lookup ('file', 'new_state_list_per_line').splitlines()}}"
    all_states: "{{ shipping_var['country.states.availability'] + new_states | unique | sort }}"
  set_fact:
    shipping_var: "{{ shipping_var | combine({'country.states.availability': all_states}) }}"
```

To push the content back into the original file, you just have to write out the content of the var back to the file in yaml format with the `copy` module for example:

```yaml
- name: Update file with new content if needed
  copy:
    dest: path/to/shipping.yml
    content: "{{ shipping_var | to_yaml }}"
    owner: someuser
    group: somegroup
    mode: 0640
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But in above case, how would I update back into the file? I would encounter the same problem while updating the file.  So in your suggestion the key-name (country.states.availability) is still not updated

Comment: Where did you talk about updating the key name ? To update the file simply push the content of the var back into it, with the copy module. I'll add an update for that

Comment: thanks for it. Understand it. Will wait to see if there is an easy method directly to update the key field as it is a yaml.